# Recyclerview en Fragment con bottomnavigationview - PointerExcepcionNull

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin

tengo la intencion de inflar datos en mi fragment_curso.xml, por medio de un recyclerniew que esta en este, todo es controlado por un BottomnavigationView, pero al ser ejecutado me muestra un error de pointernullexception, el error es reflejado en el onActivityCreated, he inicializado las variables que utilizo en null con respecto a la linea que refleja el error, supongo que por mi inexperiencia no logro entenderlo, por esto pido vuestra ayuda comunidad. adjunto:

Cursofragment
    '''

```
    private lateinit var fragment : Fragment
        private var adapter: MainAdapter? = null
        private var titulo: TextView? = null
        private  var pagina: TextView? = null
        private  var link: TextView? = null
        private  var descripcion: TextView? = null
        private var recyclerViewCurso: RecyclerView? = null
        private var imagenUrl: CircleImageView? = null

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cursos, container, false)
            titulo = (view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txtTitle) as? TextView)!!
            //slider=(ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.slider);
            pagina = (view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txtPage) as? TextView)!!
            descripcion = (view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txtDesc) as? TextView)!!
            link = (view.findViewById<View>(R.id.txtLink) as? TextView)!!
            recyclerViewCurso = (view.findViewById<View>(R.id.recyclerViewCurso) as? RecyclerView)!!
            imagenUrl = (view.findViewById<View>(R.id.circleImageView) as? CircleImageView)!!


            return view
        }
            override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

                this.adapter = (fragment).let { fragment.context?.let { it1 -> MainAdapter(it1) } }!!
                recyclerViewCurso?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(fragment.context)
                recyclerViewCurso?.adapter = adapter

                val dummyList = mutableListOf<Curso>()
                dummyList.add(Curso("https://www.cursosgis.com/wp-content/uploads/2-25.jpg", "CURSO PROFESIONAL DE PYTHON", "https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/python-web",
                        "Curso Orientado al desarrollo Web"))

                adapter?.setListData(dummyList)
                adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                return
            }
    }  

'''
```

fragment_curso.xml

'''

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Fragment.CursosFragment">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCurso"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

'''

curso_item_row

'''

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Titulo"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pagina"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDesc"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descripcion"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Link"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

'''

MainAdapter

'''

```
class MainAdapter(private val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder>() {


    private var dataList = mutableListOf<Curso>()
    fun setListData(data: MutableList<Curso>) {
        dataList = data
    }

    inner class MainViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindView(curso: Curso) {
            Glide.with(context).load(curso.imagenUrl).into(itemView.circleImageView)
            itemView.txtTitle.text = curso.titulo
            itemView.txtPage.text = curso.pagina
            itemView.txtLink.text = curso.link
            itemView.txtDesc.text = curso.descripcion
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainViewHolder {
        val View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.curso_item_row, parent, false)
        return MainViewHolder(View)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if (dataList.size > 0) {
            dataList.size
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val curso = dataList[position]
        holder.bindView(curso)
    }
}
```

'''

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante revisar [ask] que te brinda información acerca de 

como formular preguntas en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado o investigado, agrega el código como texto no como imagen. 

No olvides realizar el [tour]  del sitio, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la apreciación, soy realmente nuevo en este mundo de desarrollo agradezco tu aclaración

Comment: Gracias por editar tu pregunta, dónde se muestra el nullpointerexception, agrega el mensaje de error que se muestra en el LogCat.

Comment: Lo hare en un momento, ya he arreglado el error, pero subiré la respuesta, para que otros con ese mismo error, tengan donde apoyarse.